# Particle simulation as fluid inflow

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I have a scene with a fluid domain and a particle simulation. How would I use the particle simulation as an inflow for the fluid domain? (I'm using Blender 2.90)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add and configure the particle simulation to a mesh
- set this mesh as "flow", under "flow source" choose "particle system" instead of the default choice that is "mesh"
- cache the simulation in the domain
- you did it!

[image]